# open a div having id using onclick in a hyperlink

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, onclick

below is the given div having id "panel" and  links in the same page but outside this div, when I click on the link this div should be open. there are several links so jquery does not work and my button is created dynamically through php while loop hence i cannot put unique id in my hyperlink

```
   <div id="panel">
<form name="userloginform" action="xxx.php" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="tb">
   <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" height="80">User Name</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">:&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="user" type="text" class="log"/></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">Password</td>
     <td align="left" valign="middle">:&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="pass" type="password" class="log"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><input name="submit1" type="submit" value="Login" class="login_btn"/></td>
 </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  </div>
```

and my link is

```
 <a href="#" id="flip" >Launch Now</a>
 <a href="#" id="" >Launch Now</a>
```

If I am not clear please reply which part is not clear so that I can edit and provide useful information clearly

ok here is where link is coming from, a CMS is used here.

```
   <?php
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM heading ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $ii=$r['id'];
    ?>
      <h3><?php echo $r['heading'];?></h3>
      <div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="main_table_wrapper">
            <table width="1030" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
            <?php
                    $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inner_table WHERE head='$ii'") ;
                    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
                    {
                    $abc=str_replace($rows['url'],'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',$rows['url']); 
                    ?>
              <tr>

                <th align="left" valign="middle" width="350"><?php echo $rows['inner_names'];?></th>
                <th align="left" valign="middle" width="250"><?php echo $abc;?></th>
                <th align="left" valign="middle" width="200"><?php echo $rows['author'];?></th>
                <th align="center" valign="middle" width="100"><?php echo $rows['doe'];?></th>
                <th align="right" valign="middle" width="130"><span class="lunch"><a href="#" id="flip1">Launch Now</a></span></th>

              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
         </table>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why won't jquery work? Show your javascript. etc.

Comment: why jquery will not work here and inside loop why you can't put id to every <a>?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Since you didn't show any JS code so far, the only advice I can give is to use a class as the identifier for the action link.

From the look of your markup you could also use something along
`$('span.lunch').on('click', 'a', function(e) { //do stuff } );`